# Why projection fields are not getting set while fetching data using projection by joining two unrelated entities in JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to get some specific column values using projection by joining two unrelated entities. But I am not getting any values.
Repository code is:-

```
    @Repository
    public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
        @Query("SELECT p.id,p.firstName,p.lastName,a.city FROM Person p INNER JOIN Address a on p.id = a.personId")
        public List<PersonAndAddressSummary> findAllPersonSummary();
    }
```

Person class

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private long phone;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

```
Address class

    @Entity
    public class Address {
        @Id
        private int id;
        private String street;
        private String state;
        private int personId;
        private String country;
        private int houseNo;
        private String city;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }

        public void setStreet(String street) {
            this.street = street;
        }

        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public int getPersonId() {
            return personId;
        }

        public void setPersonId(int personId) {
            this.personId = personId;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public int getHouseNo() {
            return houseNo;
        }

        public void setHouseNo(int houseNo) {
            this.houseNo = houseNo;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }
    }
```

Projection interface

```
public interface PersonAndAddressSummary {
    public String getId();

    public String getFirstName();

    public String getLastName();

    public String getCity();
}
```

After executing this Spring Boot application, the output I am getting is this.

```
[{"lastName":null,"firstName":null,"city":null,"id":null},{"lastName":null,"firstName":null,"city":null,"id":null},{"lastName":null,"firstName":null,"city":null,"id":null}]
```

Though there are records available which match perfectly for each Person in Address class(data available in person and address table).

Answer (score 1):

If there is no join between two entities then you can't get data of other entity.Every repository is class specific in jpa. You have to define different projection for each class.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p")
public List<PersonAndSummary> findAllPersonSummary();
}


@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {
@Query("SELECT a FROM Address a where a.personId=:personId")
public AddressSummary findAddressSummary(@Param("personId") int personId);
}



public interface PersonSummary {
   public String getId();
   public String getFirstName();
   public String getLastName();
}


public interface AddressSummary {

   public String getCity();
}


public interface PersonAndAddressSummary extends PersonSummary, AddressSummary{
 }
```

Now in your service class find list of personSummary. Now iterate this list and get AddressSummary by personId.

```
List<PersonSummary> personSummaryList = yourRepositoryName.findAllPersonSummary();
List<PersonAndAddressSummary> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(PersonSummary summary: personSummaryList){
  AddressSummary addressSummary = repositoryName.findAddressSummary(summary.getId());
//now add required fields in your list
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this? I want specific column data by joining two entities from both the tables.

Comment: You can do by defining an interface which extends all interfaces whome you want to combine.

Comment: I am editing the answer if you have problem yet. You can see that.

Comment: You are saying, I should create two more interfaces, AddressRepository and PersonAddressRepository. Then PersonAddressRepository should extend PersonRepository and AddressRepository?

Comment: Yes ,because I did not find any way to join two table without relation in jpa. If you can find a way then you don't have to add extra interfaces.

Comment: Okay. Will check this.

Comment: Can you show me how will you use PersonAndAddressSummary as projection in a repository? Means what should I call that new repository?

Comment: I suggest you to make a relation between entity. You just need to make change in your Address class. Change [private int personId]  to -> [private Person person] and annotate with "@OneToOne". Then your code is going to work fine by making some changes in you jpa query.

Comment: And if you can't do this or don't want to do this see my edited code above.

Comment: Actually this is just an example I proposed. I have an existing system where the changes cannot be made but the requirements are similar.

Comment: Can I use PersonAndAddressSummary in any of the above repositories?

Comment: No you can not use.